# Why use private lock over intrinsic lock?

Tags: java, synchronization, locking

While reading about synchronization, I came across "monitor pattern" to encapsulate mutable states.

The following is the sample code

```
   public class MonitorLock {
      private final Object myLock = new Object();
      Widget widget;
      void someMethod() {
        synchronized(myLock) {
         // Access or modify the state of widget
        }
    }
```

}

Is it better in any way to have a private lock instead of the intrinsic lock?

Comment: Had to edit question title - as you wound up asking the opposite, and I'm curious as to the original question :P

Comment: "encapsulate mutable states." what do you mean when you write this? because of you use final, it is immutable, is not it?

Comment: @grep: `myLock` is final; `widget` is not... and even if it were, it could be mutable itself.

Comment: Using the "final" keyword makes the the variable you are declaring immutable.   As I understand "encapsulate mutable states." in the question means that access to the fields, for instance to the Widget, is permitted only    from one thread. is not it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes - it means you can see *all the code which could possibly acquire that lock* (leaving aside the possibility of reflection).

If you lock on `this` (which is what I assume you're referring to by "the intrinsic lock") then other code can do:

```
MonitorLock foo = new MonitorLock();
synchronized(foo) {
    // Do some stuff
}
```

This code may be a long way away from `MonitorLock` itself, and may call other methods which in turn take out monitors. It's easy to get into deadlock territory here, because you can't easily see what's going to acquire which locks.

With a "private" lock, you can easily see *every piece of code* which acquires that lock, because it's all within `MonitorLock`. It's therefore easier to reason about that lock.

Comment: You said "and may call other methods which in turn take out monitors" . Can you put some code snippet to show how this can happen actually ? If the method call is inside synchronized block , how can it escape the lock ?

Comment: @Subhra: The point is that *any other code* which has the reference to the "intrinsic lock" could end up trying to synchronize on it. It could try to do so in one thread when you're trying to synchronize it on another, for example... even when really there's nothing which requires locking *on that monitor*.

Comment: Can I also rephrase the answer as "using a public lock can result in leaking implementation details to the callers"?

Comment: @Subhra: *Sort of* - but not just to callers, and it's more "incidentally" exposed than anything else.

Comment: @grep: Why did you add this as a comment on my *answer*, which doesn't include that at all?

Comment: @grep: Right, so I can see why you'd add the comment to the *question*, but not the *answer*.