# What does "A synchronized block in Java is synchronized on some object" mean..?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I understand that to achieve thread safety and synchronization we use either synchronized block or method.
But I am not able to understand the statement-
"A synchronized block in Java is synchronized **on some object**"

Any real world example will be helpful.

Comment: when you use `synchronized`, you are always acquiring the lock of an object. you are not locking the method or the block of code.

Comment: The JVM needs _somewhere_ to store the information about the lock.

Comment: For a real world example that shows some deliberations in choosing a good object to lock on see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513227/why-use-private-lock-over-intrinsic-lock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect of `synchronized` is that only one thread at a time can execute the synchronized code. But if we look at the details, that's not the whole truth.

Suppose we have two Vectors `A` and `B` and want to call various methods from different threads. The `Vector` class is thread-safe by synchronizing all important methods. When thread T1 executes `A.add(5,"abc")`, why should that block a different thread from executing `B.get(5)`? They have no data elements in common, so executing both calls in parallel won't hurt.

And here comes the notion of "synchronized on A": The `Vector` methods synchronize on the `Vector` instance, so at most one thread can execute synchronized code **for any given Vector**.

So Vector A synchronizes on A, and Vector B on B. So, no two threads can manipulate the Vector A in parallel, but one thread can work on A, and another one independently on B.

- With the `synchronized(object) { ... }` construct, you decide on the object you want to synchronize on.
- Using the `synchronized` keyword on an instance method, you get synchronization on the current (`this`) object, so every instance gets its own synchronization.
- Using the `synchronized` keyword on a static method, you get synchronization on the class, so you get protection against all other `static synchronized` methods of this class, independent of any instance.

Answer (score 2):

3 usages of synchronized keyword.

---

Explictly:

```
final Object object = new Object();
synchronized(object) {

}
```

---

Instance synchronized method

```
synchronized void foo() {

}
```

it will use current instance as monitor lock, which equals:

```
void foo() {
    synchronized (this) {

    }
}
```

So when you call `foo` on different instances, they will not effect each other.

---

Class synchronized method

```
class Exmaple {

    static synchronized void foo() {

    }

}
```

it will use current class object as monitor lock, which equals:

```
class Exmaple {

    static void foo() {
        synchronized (Exmaple.class) {

        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization takes a lock (Object level lock or Class level lock) on an object before executing the synchronized block.

A synchronized block in Java thus is synchronized on the object on which it takes the lock.

For example:

```
synchronized (this)  // Lock on current object
synchronized (lockObject) // Lock on an object lockObject
synchronized(ClassA.class) // Lock on ClassA
```

Comment: can we pass any object as a parameter..?

Comment: Yes, you will take a lock on that object.