# Locking on static final object attribute vs locking code based on class type

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, monitor

I'm seeing some multithreading issues when running safe1 method here :

```
    public class Test {

    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    public void safe1() {
        //Some non thread safe code
        synchronized (lock) {
            //Some thread safe code
        }
        //Some non thread safe code.
    }
    
    public void safe2() {
        //Some non thread safe code
        synchronized (lock) {
            //Some thread safe code
        }
        //Some non thread safe code.
    }
}
```

I was thinking it has the same behavior than this code.

```
public class Test {

    public void safe1() {
        //Some non thread safe code
        synchronized (Test.class) {
            //Some thread safe code
        }
        //Some non thread safe code.
    }
    
    public void safe2() {
        //Some non thread safe code
        synchronized (Test.class) {
            //Some thread safe code
        }
        //Some non thread safe code.
    }
}
```

Is that correct?
I want to ensure no 2 threads are running the same "safe code", VM wide.

Comment: Depends if any other code tried to synchronize on the same object or class.

Comment: @khelwood Can you elaborate? I have many instances of type Test running. I want to ensure no 2 threads are running the same "safe code", VM wide. Is synchronized (lock) same as synchronized (Test.class) ?

Comment: Do you have any *other* code doing `synchronized (Test.class)` or a synchronized static method on the Test class, or any other methods in the Test class using the `lock` object? If so, then `safe1` and `safe2` are different, because they would be sharing locks with different pieces of other code.

Comment: @khelwood I have other several methods using synchronized (lock). I don't have a mix of the methods to synchronize. So the real question is : Is a set of methods using the synchronized (lock) is the same as the set of methods using synchronized (Test.class). I'll be using one of the methods, not both.

Comment: If all the code is using the same lock, then as as far as I know it shouldn't matter if the lock is a class or an object. If some code is changed to use a different lock while other still uses the same lock, then you would have different behaviour because two things sharing a lock is different from two things having different locks.

Comment: Possibly related: [Why use private lock over intrinsic lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7513227)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is somebody could write code acquiring a lock like

```
synchronized(Test.class) {
```

and be able to acquire the lock without calling the methods on a Test object. Any arbitrary code in the application could acquire the lock and possibly prevent your other code using it from progressing.  Locking on a private field makes that harder, the code would have to get the private field with reflection and the security manager could be configured to prevent that.

Otherwise the scoping of the lock is the same, you're letting in one thread at a time across all instances of the Test class for the whole classloader. So creating more Test instances doesn't help your concurrency level. If you are protecting instance data then that would seem unnecessarily constricting. The locking scope should be the same as the scope of the data you're preventing concurrent access to.

If the Test class is loaded by two different classloaders, then you will have two separate copies of the Test class. Whether Test.class is unique across the application depends on how the application is using classloaders. But neither of your approaches is preferable with respect to that.

Answer (score 0):

This code will not allow to any other thread to take access in the same class loader of the jvm.