# Count to 10 but thread waits other thread before starting

Tags: java, concurrency

I would like to create a program like this:
I start in my main 10 threads like this (My class implements runnable)

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] ar) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        Count1by1 count1by1 = new Count1by1(i);
        Thread myThread = new Thread(count1by1);
        myThread.start();
    }   
 }
}
```

and I want to create a critical section that if the thread enters it can count to 10, if not it will wait().
I've tried many implementations but is not working (cuz every threads count to 10 without waiting...

This is the class

```
public class Count1by1 implements Runnable{
private int threadnumber;
private Object mutex = new Object();


public Count1by1(int num) {
    this.threadnumber=num;
    //this.mutex= new Object();
}

public void count() {
    synchronized (mutex) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("#"+threadnumber + " counts: " + i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void run() {
    count();
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont fully understand what you are trying to do. Why needs to wait? What it waits for?

Comment: I would like to do something like this, I create many threads but they can't count 1 to 10 concurrently, only and only 1 can count 1to10, so I think that the others have to wait no?

Comment: Unrelated but avoid `class MyTask extends Thread{..}` always prefer `class MyTask implements Runnable{..}`. Extending Thread class involves few mechanisms which you may not want (especially if you are not aware of it).

Comment: the other threads wait untile a thread finished counting, then the faster thread will enter in the critical section and start counting. BTW my bad not extends thread but implements runnable, ty

Comment: So only 1 counts to 10 and others do nothing ?

Comment: Yes! Only count 1to10

Comment: Mutex needs to be between objects. And if only 1 thread can do the counting you need to add something to kill the others then.

Comment: You said, "I would like to...create many threads but [not let them] count 1 to 10 concurrently." Concurrency is the _entire point_ of creating threads. It only ever makes sense to create a thread if there is something that it can do concurrently with other threads. You might learn something by doing this exercise, but it's not something you should ever do in any real program.

Comment: So, it's now looking like you did in fact create a new account for the now deleted question, and then misrepresented this fact

Answer (score 1):

> ```java
> private Object mutex = new Object();
> ```

Okay. You create a new object. It has no name (because objects do not have names). You also created a field (which isn't an object; it's a pointer to one). It currently points at the new object you made.

Each of the 10 instances of Count1by1 has a field, and each points to a unique object, given that they all run `new Object()`.

> ```java
> synchronized (mutex) {
> ```

Okay, this takes the field `mutex` follows what its pointing at, finds the object there, and then locks on that. Given that there are 10 unique objects (each Count1by1 instance has its own object), this accomplishes nothing. To have a mutex, at least 2 threads need to lock on the same object.

### Solution

Make the lock object in your main and pass it to your threads:

```
private final Object mutex;

public Count1by1(int num, Object mutex) {
    this.threadnumber=num;
    this.mutex = mutex;
}
```

Now there's one mutex object (hint: Count the number of times the code executes a `new` statement, that's how many you have). Each of your 10 instances of Count1by1 has its own field, but they are all pointing at the same object (it's like 10 people having a piece of paper with the same home address written on it: 10 'variables', just one house), hence, synchronizing on them will do something.

Comment: PERFECT! now I solved ty mannnn!
So to complete the all thing I have to create an object as a locker in my main right?
But what is the purpose to the private "final" Object mutex here?

Comment: @FilResto, Re, "...purpose to the `private final Object mutex`?" Your version also had a `private final Object mutex`. In both examples, its purpose is the same: It declares the _field_ that holds the reference to an `Object` that your program uses as a mutex. The only difference is, in your original version, the `mutex` in each `Count1by1` instance held a reference to a _different object._ rzwitserloot wants them all to refer to the _same object._ That change fixes your problem because `synchronized` only means anything when two or more threads try to synchronize on the _same object._

Comment: @FilResto "*But what is the purpose to the private "final" Object mutex here*" possibly related: [Why use private lock over intrinsic lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7513227)